# Same public key differs with the way to get it

Tags: python, ssl, openssl, cryptography, rsa

I'm writting a little program using SSL sockets. A client sends values to a server and when the server gets the value it checks the client's public key to make sure he's expected to send something. So at first the server is getting all the public keys like this :

```
       cert = f.read()
       crtObj = crypto.load_certificate(crypto.FILETYPE_PEM, cert)
       pubKeyObject = crtObj.get_pubkey()
       pubKeyString = crypto.dump_publickey(crypto.FILETYPE_PEM,pubKeyObject)
```

with this method, the public key is :

b'-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----\nMIIBIjANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQEFAAOCAQ8AMIIBCgKCAQEA7GIzek5JgfFzFCGwnx7X\ncE4QULV/9uyoGgd9HbHYyYcItEcSPU39ORXCrNQGxh09k4oFPBYntjD2gIORF8V4\n6EAC10bFaT18OuM1F/37v+K/+BuvCDTqcS9Y0CRalwPFVYB+yttvZ8fnvO2l/TxF\nsLmZh0yY/ajaHxey/ppUQycGy4xA8XD6VlWFM7+I0t/19rrLN9iMFSym/TgYpBbn\nxyZel8rMW/ACS09nSprEu1BuI+myhhej+cuy3wU8byRTwANpqHxsx5cTwp642TVx\nBKbuO8GHAzEKcrFZnrKcsXr9emWV5ouYiVzehOT4Pd3I2W8qSy6x/Ovv/iS3ojT4\ndQIDAQAB\n-----END PUBLIC KEY-----\n'

and when the server wants to get it from the socket connection like this :

```
       test1 = writer.get_extra_info('ssl_object')
       der =test1.getpeercert(binary_form=True)
       test = test1.getpeercert()
       cert = x509.Certificate.load(der)
       pubkey= cert.public_key.unwrap()
       print(pem.armor("PUBLIC KEY", pubkey.contents).decode("ASCII"))
```

the public key printed is :

-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----
AoIBAQDsYjN6TkmB8XMUIbCfHtdwThBQtX/27KgaB30dsdjJhwi0RxI9Tf05FcKs
1AbGHT2TigU8Fie2MPaAg5EXxXjoQALXRsVpPXw64zUX/fu/4r/4G68INOpxL1jQ
JFqXA8VVgH7K229nx+e87aX9PEWwuZmHTJj9qNofF7L+mlRDJwbLjEDxcPpWVYUz
v4jS3/X2uss32IwVLKb9OBikFufHJl6Xysxb8AJLT2dKmsS7UG4j6bKGF6P5y7Lf
BTxvJFPAA2mofGzHlxPCnrjZNXEEpu47wYcDMQpysVmespyxev16ZZXmi5iJXN6E
5Pg93cjZbypLLrH86+/+JLeiNPh1AgMBAAE=
-----END PUBLIC KEY-----

So I don't know if it's a matter of format or if it's really not the same public key I'm getting... but it should be.
Sorry for the long post and thank you very much for reading.

Answer (score 0):

Most(if not all) base64 encoding variants use A-Z, a-z, 0-9 characters to represent data the total is 62 character and some base64 encodings varies in the last 2 characters but most of them use `+` and `/` which will complete 64. So the above 2 keys seems to be completely different and the second key is also padded because of `=` sign at end. The standard base64 encoding is `RFC 4648` variant which use `+` and `/` and make padding as optional not mandatory like `RFC 4880 openpgp` base64 encoding.

Comment: Ok thank you, would you have any idea why I'm not getting the same key ?

Comment: @LoLoVoulzy just took a look at the code you seems to decode second  public key content as ```ASCII```. Which will make the content be decoded as ASCII while first key is being decoded as Base64 data. You can try to change the way you read one of the keys to match the other key.

Answer (score 0):

It was in fact the same keys but the way of getting it was wrong : here the right one from the ssl object :

```
    test1 = writer.get_extra_info('ssl_object')
    der =test1.getpeercert(binary_form=True)
    crtObj = crypto.load_certificate(crypto.FILETYPE_ASN1, der)
    pubKeyObject = crtObj.get_pubkey()
    pubKeyString = crypto.dump_publickey(crypto.FILETYPE_PEM, pubKeyObject)
```